# how to add text to arbitrary form field with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple fields. I'd like to have a link that could add a `<br />` to whichever input the cursor is in. How would I get that input field? like:

```
<script>
$('body').on('click','.add-break', function(){
   // how to get a reference to the input where the cursor is selected and then add a 
   // <br /> there        
});
</script>

<div class='add-break'>add break</div>
<input type='text' name='header' />
<input type='text' name='detail' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a catch22 here, as when you click the `div.add-break`, you lose the focus of the input. So you need to keep track of the last focused input.

http://jsfiddle.net/64Lpvms4/

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(){
    $('.focus').removeClass('focus');
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});


jQuery('.add-break').click(function(){
  $('.focus').val('<br>');
});
```

```css
.focus { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='add-break'>add break</div>
<input type='text' name='header' />
<input type='text' name='detail' />
```

Comment: thx, that's fancy with the inline code - must be a new feature. So I get that we're losing focus when clicking the '.add-break' but I don't fully get what you are doing in the first part like it would seem like this puts focus on the current element.

Comment: no, it is marking the most recently focused input with a class of 'focus', so that when you click on your 'add-break' div, the break tag is added to the correct element.